# How to browse messages from a queue using Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I need to browse messages from an active mq using Camel route without consuming the messages.

The messages in the JMS queue are to be read(only browsed and not consumed) and moved to a database while ensuring that the original queue remains intact.

```java
public class CamelStarter {

    private static CamelContext camelContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);

        camelContext.addComponent("jms",  JmsComponent.jmsComponent(connectionFactory));

        camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("jms:queue:testQueue").to("browse:orderReceived") .to("jms:queue:testQueue1");
            }

        }
                );

        camelContext.start();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        inspectReceivedOrders();

        camelContext.stop();

    }

    public static void inspectReceivedOrders() {

        BrowsableEndpoint browse = camelContext.getEndpoint("browse:orderReceived", BrowsableEndpoint.class);
        List<Exchange> exchanges = browse.getExchanges();
        System.out.println("Browsing queue: "+ browse.getEndpointUri() + " size: " + exchanges.size());
        for (Exchange exchange : exchanges) {
            String payload = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
            String msgId = exchange.getIn().getHeader("JMSMessageID", String.class);
            System.out.println(msgId + "=" +payload);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache camel browse component is exactly designed for that.  Check [here](http://camel.apache.org/browse.html) for the documentation.

Can't say more since you have not provided any other information.

Let's asssume you have a route like this

```java
from("activemq:somequeue).to("bean:someBean")
```

or

```java
from("activemq:somequeue).process(exchange -> {})
```

All you got to do it put a browse endpoint in between like this

```java
from("activemq:somequeue).to("browse:someHandler").to("bean:someBean")
```

Then write a class like this

```java
    @Component
    public class BrowseQueue {
    
      @Autowired
      CamelContext camelContext;
    
      public void inspect() {
        BrowsableEndpoint browse = camelContext.getEndpoint("browse:someHandler", BrowsableEndpoint.class);
        List<Exchange> exchanges = browse.getExchanges();
    
        
        for (Exchange exchange : exchanges) {
          ...... 
        }
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it didn't work. Please read the updated question description.

Comment: This code snippet is creating a copy of the exchanges between the two queues. However, the messages from the queue are lost while reading.

Comment: who is supposed to consume the messages in the queue and how is the consumer consuming? can you show the route you have

Comment: what is jms:queue:testQueue1 and what are you doing in inspectOrders? care to explain?

Comment: jms:queue:testQueue1 : It is a queue name in active mq

Comment: public static void inspectReceivedOrders() {
    
    BrowsableEndpoint browse = camelContext.getEndpoint("browse:orderReceived", BrowsableEndpoint.class);
    List<Exchange> exchanges = browse.getExchanges();
    System.out.println("Browsing queue: "+ browse.getEndpointUri() + " size: " + exchanges.size());
    for (Exchange exchange : exchanges) {
      String payload = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
      String msgId = exchange.getIn().getHeader("JMSMessageID", String.class);
      System.out.println(msgId + "=" +payload);
  }
}

Comment: you can update the question with the code instead of commenting. can you explain the code flow. is it that you get messages from `jms:queue:testQueue`  and then pass to `jms:queue:testQueue1`  and then what you do with messages in `jms:queue:testQueue` ?

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned, I am reading messages from jms:queue:testQueue and then passsing them to jms:queue:testQueue1 
On reading the messages from jms:queue:testQueue, the messages are lost from the queue, whereas I do not want the original queue to be altered.

Comment: there is no such thing as browsing a queue. You can only browse it when it is being transferred from route to other . That is why you are introducing browse endpoint in between testQueue and testQueue1. Yes after the message is read from testQueue it will be removed and sent to testQueue1. That is how queues work. Once u read the messages it is gone.

Comment: Thank you.  
My problem statement requires a way such that the messages from the queue aren't lost. This is a major constraint. Can you suggest an alternate way other than Camel which can get this done?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, not possible in Camel to read (without consuming !) JMS messages...
The only workaround I found (in a JEE app) was to define a startup EJB with a timer, holding a `QueueBrowser`, and delegating the msg processing to a Camel route:

```java
    @Singleton
    @Startup
    public class MyQueueBrowser  {
    
        private TimerService timerService;
        
        @Resource(mappedName="java:/jms/queue/com.company.myqueue")
        private Queue sourceQueue;
        
        @Inject
        @JMSConnectionFactory("java:/ConnectionFactory")
        private JMSContext jmsContext;  
        
        @Inject
        @Uri("direct:readMessage")
        private ProducerTemplate camelEndpoint;
        
    
        @PostConstruct
        private void init() {       
            TimerConfig timerConfig = new TimerConfig(null, false);
            ScheduleExpression se = new ScheduleExpression().hour("*").minute("*/"+frequencyInMin);
            timerService.createCalendarTimer(se, timerConfig);
        }
        
        
        @Timeout
        public void scheduledExecution(Timer timer) throws Exception {      
            QueueBrowser browser = null;
            try {                       
                browser = jmsContext.createBrowser(sourceQueue);                                           
                Enumeration<Message> msgs = browser.getEnumeration();
                while ( msgs.hasMoreElements() ) { 
                    Message jmsMsg = msgs.nextElement(); 
                    // + here: read body and/or properties of jmsMsg                                            
                    camelEndpoint.sendBodyAndHeader(body, myHeaderName, myHeaderValue);
                }                                                                               
            } catch (JMSRuntimeException jmsException) {
                ...
            } finally {        
                browser.close();
            }
        }
    
        
    }
```